# Maximum eigenvalue of rank 1 update matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck with the following problem. The ingredients are:

- $A=diag(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, $a_i \in (0,1)$ and $a_1+\dots+a_n=1$,
- $B=diag(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, $b_i \in (0,1)$ and $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_n$,
- the entries of the matrices $A$ and $B$ are related by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i {b_i \over 1- b_i}<1$.

Denote ${\bf b}^T=(\sqrt{a_1} b_1,\dots,\sqrt{a_n}b_n)$, $c={1 \over \sum_{i=1}^n a_i (1-b_i)}$. The problem is to prove that the maximum eigenvalue of the matrix $D=B+ c {\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}$ is less than 1.

I've been studying the steady-state distribution of the two-dimensional Markov chain. Its steady-state vector turned out to be ${\vec p}_k={\vec p}_1 D^{k-1}$, $k \ge 1$. As usual, ${\vec p}_1$ is found from the normalization condition, which requires evaluation of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^k$. To make it $(I-D)^{-1}$, the aforementioned proof is required. My numerous numerical expreiments show that the maximum eigenvalue is $<1$. But I cannot prove it.

What I've tried and failed:

- interative methods (like power iteration) don't help since the power $D^k$ does not have a nice expression.
- Gershgorin theorem does not help, since some entries of $D {\vec 1}$ may be $>1$.
- the matrix $c {\bf b} {\bf b}^{T} $ is of rank 1 and has one eigenvalue $\rho=c \sum_{i=1}^n {a_ib_i^2}$. This matrix is symmetric.
- the eigenvalues of $D$ are all different and do satisfy the well-known secular equation $f(\lambda)=0$, where:
  $$
  f(\lambda)=1+ c \sum_{i=1}^n {a_i b_i^2 \over b_i - \lambda}.
  $$
- denote the roots of $f(\lambda)=0$ by $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. According to the theory, the roots satisfy the inequalities:
  $$
  b_1<\lambda_1<b_2<\lambda_2<\dots<b_n<\lambda_n.
  $$
  This does not help since the upper bound for the maximum eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ remains unknown. The theory says that $\lambda_i=b_i+m_i \rho$, where $m_i \in (0,1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i=1$. But I can't prove that $\lambda_n=b_n+m_n\rho<1$.
- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i {b_i \over 1- b_i}<1$ is equivalent to $1<\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {a_i \over 1-b_i}<2$. Since $\sum_i (u_i/v_i) \sum_i (u_iv_i) \ge 1$ we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i (1-b_i)>{1 \over2}$ and thus $1<c<2$.
- one of the classical inequalities gives
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i (1-b_i)+ (1-b_1)(1-b_r) \sum_{i=1}^n {a_i \over 1-b_i} \le 2- b_1-b_r,
  $$
  and thus
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i (1-b_i) \le 2- b_1-b_n - (1-b_1)(1-b_n) = 1-b_1 b_n <1,
  $$
  and thus, instead of $1<c<2$ we have ${1 \over 1-b_1 b_n}<c<2$. Moreover, since $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i (1-b_i)>{1\over 2}$, from the last inequality we get
  ${1\over 2} \le 1-b_1 b_n$ or $b_1 b_n < {1\over 2}$. Since $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_n$ we have
  $$
  b_1 b_i < {1\over 2}.
  $$

Unfortunately, all this did not help me to make a step towards the proof and I would be grateful for any useful suggestions.

Comment: for your 3rd bullet, you wrote *"...But this matrix is not symmetric. So the techniques for investigating the eigenvalues of the sum of two symmetric matrices (as those in the books by Golub and Wilkinson) don't work here."*  Why not make it symmetric via similarity transform?  $Z:=A^\frac{1}{2}DA^\frac{-1}{2} = B + c\cdot A^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf {bb}^T A^\frac{1}{2}$  noting that $A^\frac{1}{2}B=BA^\frac{1}{2}$ since they are both diagonal.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you, i did not notice that. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I have found the solution. It is given by the Example 7.10.3 on page 620 in here [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100307024258/http://www.matrixanalysis.com/Chapter7.pdf).
Specifically, if a matrix $H$ is non-negative then its maximum eigenvalue, say $\rho(H)$, satisfies $\rho(H)<r$ if and only if $(rI-H)^{-1}$ exists and $(rI-H)^{-1}\ge 0$.

Let us consider the matrix $(I-D)^{-1}$. Due to Sherman–Morrison formula
this inverse is equal to
$$
(I-D)^{-1}=(I-B)^{-1} + c {(I-B)^{-1} {\bf b} {\bf b}^{T} (I-B)^{-1} \over 1 - c {\bf b}^T (I-B)^{-1} {\bf b} }
= \underbrace{(I-B)^{-1}}_{\ge 0 \, component-wise\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} + {c \over \alpha} (I-B)^{-1} \underbrace{{\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}}_{\ge 0} (I-B)^{-1}, 
$$
and exists if and only if $\alpha \neq 0$. By direct inspection the value of $\alpha$ is equal to
$$
\alpha=1-c\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i b_i^2 \over 1-b_i}
$$
and clearly $\alpha\neq 0$, and thus $(I-D)^{-1}$ exists.

Now notice that $(I-D)^{-1}\ge 0$ if ${c\over \alpha}>0$. The value of $\alpha$ can be rewritten:
$$
\alpha=1-c\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i (b_i-1+1)^2 \over 1-b_i}=
c \left (2-\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i \over 1-b_i} \right )
=
c \left (1- \sum_{i=1}^n {a_i b_i \over 1-b_i} \right ).
$$
Thus ${c\over \alpha}>0$ if ${1 \over \left (1- \sum\limits_{i=1}^n {a_i b_i \over 1-b_i} \right )}>0$, which is equivalent to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {a_i b_i \over 1-b_i}<1$.

Thus we can use the statement of the Example 7.10.3 and thus the maximum eigenvalue of $D$ is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is show

$D-I=\big(B-I)+ c {\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}\prec \mathbf 0$
via congruence transform, this is the same as showing
$-I + c \big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}{\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}\prec \mathbf 0$
or that the trace of that rank 1 matrix is $\lt 1$.  Rescaling by $c^{-1}$ gives the criterion
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{ b_i^2}{1-b_i}  =\text{trace}\Big( \big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}{\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}\Big)\lt c^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(1-b_i) $
if you subtract the LHS from the RHS this is equivalent to proving
$0\lt \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{(1-b_i)^2- b_i^2}{1-b_i}$  which holds because

$0$
$\lt 1 -\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{b_i}{1-b_i}$
$= \big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{1-b_i}{1-b_i}\big) - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{b_i}{1-b_i} $
$= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{1-2b_i}{1-b_i} $
$=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{(1-b_i)^2- b_i^2}{1-b_i}$
where the inequality is bullet point 3 in the original post

Comment: What does $D-I \prec \mathbf 0$ mean?

Comment: for a real symmetric matrix $H$, the notation $H\prec \mathbf 0$ means that $H$ is negative definite, i.e. it has signature $(0,n)$ or equivalently $n$ eigenvalues $\lt 0$.  And $(D-I)$ has all negative eigenvalues *iff* $D$ has all eigenvalues $\lt 1$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying $D-I \prec \mathbf 0$. But unfortunately i don't get your explanation. Specifically, $D-I \prec \mathbf 0$ means that all eigenvalues of $(D-I)$ are negative. Okay. Then you suggest the transform: $(D-I)=\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2} X \big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}$. Why are the eigenvalues of $X$ negative?

Comment: define $Z:=\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2} $ then for real symmetric (or complex Hermitian) matrices $Z^*(D-I)Z$ has the same *signature* as $(D-I)$ for any invertible $Z$.  (For this problem we are specifically saying $(D-I)$ is negative definite *iff* $Z^*(D-I)Z$ is.) This is known as **Sylvester's Law of Inertia** and e.g. is proven a couple of different ways in Meyer's "Matrix Analysis" which you linked to in your answer.   Sylvester's Law of Inertia is a much more fundamental result than e.g. Sherman-Morrison or the positivity criterion you give.  It is worth your while to master it.

Comment: Yes, surely this was a typo in my comment and $(D-I)=\big(I-B\big)^\frac{1}{2} X \big(I-B\big)^\frac{1}{2}$. Thanks for pointing Sylvester's Law of Inerita. Applying it to $(D-I)$ and $X$ we can say that $(D-I)$ and $X=-I + c \big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}{\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}$ have the same number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues. What is the next step to argue that all eigenvalues of $D$ are in $(0,1)$?

Comment: To prove all $n$ eigenvalues of $D$ are $\lt 1$, we prove the eigenvalues of $(D-I)$ are $\lt 0$. By Sylvester's Law $X$ and $(D-I)$ are *congruent* so it suffices to prove all eigenvalues of $X$ are $\lt 0$.  $X$ is real sym, so it is diagonalizable by some orthogonal $Q$, noting that $Q^T(-I)Q=-I$; after diagonalizing we see this means $X$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues $=-1$ and one eigenvalue $=-1 + c \cdot \text{trace}\Big(\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}{\bf b} {\bf b}^{T}\big(I-B\big)^\frac{-1}{2}\Big)$ and we need to show it's $\lt 0$.  (An equivalent finish is to use the matrix determinant lemma.)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately I still can't finish your argument. Let $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i, \delta_i$ be the eigenvalues of $D$, $D-I$, $X$ and $X+I$. It is proved above that $\alpha_i \neq \alpha_j$ and $\alpha_i>0$. Assume that $max_i (\alpha_i)<1$. Then $\beta_i=\alpha_i-1<0$ and $\beta_i>-1$. By Sylvester's Law, $(D-I)$ and $X$ are congruent, thus $\gamma_i<0$. Thus all eigenvalues of $X+I$ are less than 1 since $\delta_i=\gamma_i+1<1$. But why $\delta_i$ cannot be $<-2$ or $<-3$?

Comment: your most recent comment is good if you delete everything you said about $(X+I)$ -- I say this because $(X+I)$ is irrelevant to the argument and talking about its eigenvalues is a red herring.  The key thing is we have $\lambda_{max}(D)\lt 1 \iff (D-I)\prec \mathbf 0 \iff X\prec \mathbf 0$.  I proved the right hand side because it is easy.  The chain of *iff*'s takes care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you again for the input. I still cannot understand the logic. For example, let $D-I=\begin{pmatrix}-20&0\\0&-20\end{pmatrix}$. Clearly, $(D-I)\prec \mathbf 0 $. But $\lambda_{max}(D) <0$ and $|\lambda_{max}(D)|>1$.

Comment: I think you are jumping around way too much.  Your original question states **"The problem is to prove that the maximum eigenvalue of the matrix $=+^T$ is less than 1."** I proved that.  You are now talking about absolute values of eigenvalues which is a red herring.  We have  (1.) $\lambda_{max}(D)\lt 1 \iff (D-I)\prec \mathbf 0 $ (2.) $(D-I)\prec \mathbf 0  \iff X\prec \mathbf 0$  and (3.) my proof (trace criterion) that $X\prec \mathbf 0$.  Do you understand the proofs of all three?  If so the problem is done.  If not, tell me which one you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you again for input. I seek to understand, but not blindly use your argument. Think I made your argument clear to myself. Attempt: we know that eigenvalues of $D$, $d_i$, are different and positive. Assume $max(d_i)<1$. This can happen iff $(D-I)$ has only negative eigenvalues. $(D-I)$ and $X=-I+Y$ are symmetric. From Sylvester's Law: $X$ has only negative eigenvalues, say $x_i$. Theory says, that since $-I$ and $Y$ are symmetric, then $x_i=-1$, $1\le i \le n-1$, $x_n=-1+ trace(Y)$. Since $x_i<0$ for all $i$, we must have $trace(Y)<1$. From this point on, your post goes.